# keyboard issues with refurbished HP

Tags: laptop, keyboard, ps2-keyboard

This post is likely to be rife with newbie computer speak so be kind.
I recently got a refurbished HP Probook 65606. The internal keyboard types incorrect characters and the device manager shows that a PS/2 keyboard is connected, though no external keyboard is attached. I have uninstalled the PS/2 driver but it is immediately installed again upon startup. The tracker pad and in-keyboard mouse devices work fine. I know enough about using a computer to navigate internally but I know little about drivers or managing new hardware. Does this happen because there is no alternate keyboard driver to take the place of the PS/2? I suspect that the person who refurbished it used a PS/2 and not the internal keyboard. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You might have an incorrect keyboard layout set in the operating system. That's a software problem, and not anything to do with drivers or hardware. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688179.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I would return the notebook for a full refund. I don't know about you but I don't buy a laptop so I can work on it.

Answer (score 2):

Ps/2 doesn't always mean external device. Even in my own HP Elitebook, the device settings show the Keyboard as PS/2 keyboard. That's just the way it's listed.

Check 2 things:

go to [HP Driver Downloads for the HP PB 65606](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=5045607)

Select your operating system and download the latest drivers for the keyboard. 
Secondly, see what language is set. 
Control Panel - Region and Language -> Change Keyboard.